# Is there a way to detect a file read?

Tags: python, io

I know that libraries such as watchdog can provide notifications on file system *changes*, but I'm curious to know if there's a way to receive a notification that a file has simply been read.

Comment: not without explicit filesystem support. On some platforms there is an access time, but I don't know how to go about getting it from python.

Comment: I guess this also depends heavily on which FS you are using.

Comment: @TSL If you tell us your platform and filesystem, I might be more willing to do the legwork and research this. There is AFAIK no completely cross platform way to do it, and even on platforms that store access times, it may not be required to be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

[pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) can do this on Linux (via the IN_ACCESS event). I'm not aware of anything cross-platform, however.